# Class constructor Object3D cannot be invoked without 'new' at new THREE.CSS2DObject

Tags: javascript, three.js

I got this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Object3D cannot be invoked without 'new'
at new THREE.CSS2DObject
and i try to run this project:
https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph/blob/master/example/text-nodes/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that `THREE.CSS2DObject` and the core library `three.js` are from different releases. Such setups are not supported and should always be avoided.

Notice that lately the code base was migrated to ES6 classes. If you try to derive from an ES6 class with ES5 prototype style code, you will encounter the above runtime error. So it seems the code use a newer `three.js` than `THREE.CSS2DObject`.

Comment: Thank you bro you saved me :D

Comment: How can we fix this issue?

Comment: The fix for this issue was to upgrade the code that derives from `THREE.CSS2DObject` to ES6 classes.

Comment: even if i upgrade i am getting error when I use es6 way of importing